# How can I get a three-column index in the memoir class?

Tags: memoir, indexing

My MWE is far too long but this is one of my many attempts, none of which worked.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% try for 3 column index

\newif\ifthreecolindex
\newcommand{\threecolindex}{\threecolindextrue}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
  \clearforchapter
  \ifthreecolindex
    \begin{multicols}{3}
%    starting multocols 3
%
%    threecolindex

  \else
    \ifonecolindex
      \onecolumn
      onecolindex
    \else
      \setlength{\columnseprule}{indexrule}%
      \setlength{columnsep}{\indexcolsep}
      \twocolumn{\@makeschapterhead{\indexname}
                 \preindexhook}%
```

.........

```
\threecolindex
 \printindex
\end{document}
```

I have thought it best to change my GOM (Grumpy Old Man) signature to GSIOM (Grumpy Semi Incompetent Old Man).

Any help will be much appreciated and who knows, the `memoir` maintainer (daleif) might even add it to the `memoir` class, but don't hold your breath.

GSIOM

Comment: your example seems to be missing parts.

Comment: As Ulrike mentions please make a full example, it is a lot easier to work with

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something, this seems to work just fine

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% try for 3 column index

\newif\ifthreecolindex
\newcommand{\threecolindex}{\threecolindextrue}
\usepackage{multicol}


\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
  \clearforchapter
  \ifthreecolindex
      \chapter*{\indexname}
      \preindexhook
  \else
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecolfalse
    \else
      \@restonecoltrue
    \fi
    \ifonecolindex
      \onecolumn
      \chapter*{\indexname}
      \preindexhook
    \else
      \setlength{\columnseprule}{\indexrule}%
      \setlength{\columnsep}{\indexcolsep}%
      \twocolumn[\@makeschapterhead{\indexname}
                 \preindexhook]%
    \fi
  \fi               
  \indexmark
  \ifnoindexintoc\else
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}%
  \fi
  \ifthreecolindex
   \begin{multicols}{3}
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{indextitlepagestyle}\parindent\z@
  \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
  \let\item\@idxitem}%
{
  \ifthreecolindex
    \end{multicols}
  \else
    \if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\twocolumn\fi
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\makeindex

\begin{document}

test\index{A}\index{B}\index{C}


\threecolindex
 \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked fine but somehow I screwed up the prologue of the document I wanted to use it in. Any thoughts of adding it to `memoir` or as a stand-alone package?

Comment: @PeterWilson, not really. If there had been a need for it, people would have asked for it. I don't think I've ever seen a document with a three col index, you'll run out of space too fast

Comment: In my particular document the index entries are very short, one or two words and a page number. If I use a one-column document the regular index takes 49 pages. Using a two-column index it takes 25 pages but a three column index only takes 17 pages --- a significant reduction on the other formats. I certainly need a three-column index, perhaps others as well but they haven't realised it or haven't asked. Anyway, it is obviously up to you.